# Endless loading/spinner on the woocommerce checkout page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Since some recent updates , the checkout page on my site is not working. Even after entering name/address, the area under “Your order” is greyed out and spinning.

**Things I’ve tried that didn’t work:**

- *Disabled all plugins (except woocommerce)*
- *Changed theme to Default theme.*
- *Checked Woocommerce>System Status.*
- *Increased memory limit via wp-config Disabled PayPal (the only payment gateway)*
- *Removed the woocommerce files via admin and 
  uploaded a fresh version    via FTP*
- *Checked items on this page: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/endless-
  loadingspinner-on-the-checkout-page/*

I'm runngin NGINX 1.6.3 server and seems to be no issue with server as other woocommerce sites on same server works fine.

I’ve looked at the Chrome console and found this:

```
https://example.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)
```

I checked using full URL like `https://example.com/index.php?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` and it shows some ajax code but using `https://example.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` shows homepage.

Disabling Ajax completely on checkout page works but it does not update price for checkout addons like `gift wrap`.

This is config for my site:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /home/user/example.com/public/;
    index index.php;

    access_log /home/user/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/user/example.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {

        allow all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm: fastcgi_pass
        #unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools, not just at the console. The failing request is probably a POST request, so just pasting that URL into the address line isn't a good way to test it. On the network tab (at least in chrome), you can copy the request as a curl command, and then run that from the command line. Also, look at the error logs, and use WP_DEBUG, and add any info you find there to your question.

Comment: @janh I have find the problem, in server block for that site, I set `index` to `index.html` and have a bootstrap template as homepage and wordpress for all other stuff. If I change to `index.php` and remove `index.html` it works correctly. Please what should I do to keep `index.html` as default to load and that ajax should work? Should I rename index.html to index.php?

Comment: Why would you want a static page instead of WP in the first place? You could simply add a page in WP and make that your static front page.

Comment: @janh I have a static page to show some information about products and links for add to cart. I want to keep it Since those static pages loads faster.

Comment: @janh I have a static page to show some information about products and links for add to cart. I want to keep it Since those static pages loads faster.

Comment: Use caching to make your site work faster, don't manually build static html. Nginx can handle the caching for you, and so can WP.